# Sharing Joomla views across extensions

Tags: php, joomla

I created my own Joomla Library which holds a few utility functions and some views which should be shared with other extensions that need the same views.

Inside one extensions (`Redextension`) view all I do is call:

```
JLoader::import('mylib.views.objects');
```

The objects view is just a regular view:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
class RedextensionViewObjects extends JViewLegacy
{
    function display($tpl=null) {
...
```

The question is how would I go about abstracting the `Redextension` prefix because that will not work if I use that view in another extension that is called `Blueextension`.
Same goes for Models. The extensions have the same DB structure and functionality, so it would be great if I could share that within a library.

Comment: Minor text to code formats and capitalized I. Also tried to make the last two sentences flow smoother